# How do i get the selected values carried over to a new tab once the URL loads by using an event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, event-listener

How do i go about getting both chosen values to display in their boxes after the link is copied like = e.g www.example.com#135&141

At the moment it only carries over the first values from select box "CARS". I need both.

Any suggestions?

```
<select name="boats" id="boats" class="boats">
    <option value="0">CARS</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="135">135</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="136">136</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="137">137</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="139">139</option>
</select>

<select name="cars" id="cars" class="cars">
    <option value="">BOATS</option> 
    <option class="level-0" value="140">140</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="141">141</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="142">142</option>
</select>



    <script type="text/javascript">
//carries selected value to url        
    $(function(){
    $('#boats, #cars').change(function () {
       var regURL =  $('#boats').val();    
       var catURL =  $('#cars').val();    

       window.location.hash = regURL + ( catURL ? ("&" + catURL) : "" );
       console.log(window.location.hash);
    });
    });
//carries selected value to url

//keeps values selected when link is copied to new tab      
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

    window.onload = fn; // fire on pageload

    function fn() {
        var values = window.location.hash.replace('#', '').split('&')
        $('#boats').val(values[0]);
        if (values.length > 1){
            $('#cars').val(values(1));
        }
        console.log("hash = " + window.location.hash);
    }
     //keeps values selected when link is copied to new tab      
    </script>
```

Comment: `values(1)` is a function call, but to access the next property of the array use `values[1]`

Comment: @maksbd19 i've tried this but it results in the first select box to change its value back to default when a selection from the second box is made

Comment: works for me @zuh,after change values(1) to values[1]

Comment: well `split` returns an array containing an empty string rather than empty array if the hash is empty. You need to check if the hash is empty before the split.